# doctrine 2 reverse engineering issue for a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a database that i want to do some reverse engineering to tables using doctrine 2, so i used this simple commands

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force ProjectBundle yml
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities ProjectBundle
```

but the problem doctrine did not reverse engineered one join table containing two foreign keys but it did for another.
here you will find an sql statements for creating the two join tables the first have been reverse engineered the last one not

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `control`.`project_problem_place` (
  `id_place` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_problem` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_project` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_place`, `id_problem`, `id_project`),
  INDEX `FK_project1` (`id_project` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_problem1` (`id_problem` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_problem1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_problem`)
    REFERENCES `control`.`problem` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_project1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_project`)
    REFERENCES `control`.`project` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_place1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_place`)
    REFERENCES `control`.`place` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `control`.`project_code` (
  `id_project` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_code` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_project`, `id_code`),
  INDEX `FK_CODE2` (`id_code` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PROJECT2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_project`)
    REFERENCES `control`.`project` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CODE2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_code`)
    REFERENCES `control`.`code` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with __doctrine did not generate one join table__? Aren't tables already generated as you're doing entity generation from db tables?

Comment: i wanted to say that doctrine left one join table that exist in the database and did not create the mapping yml file for it when doing reverse engineering with doctrine

Comment: well when verifying the yml files generated by doctrine after reverse engineering i have found the join table defined in the project table of the project_code using manytomany so i think doctrine generated the first join table because it contains three foreing keys that's why.

Comment: Yes, thinking again to the behaviour I can confirm that is the correct deduction: two entities can be linked each other by an attribute but when you're linking three or more entities, this will be lost so doctrine need to create an entity that will represents the join table